# Gravity Forms parameters return 1

Tags: actions, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm not sure what's causing gravity forms $entry and $form parameters to return 1.

Here is my class.

```
namespace GrvityFormsIntegration\DataTools;

ini_set( 'error_log', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/debug.log' );

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No direct access!' );



class GravityFormService {


  public function __construct() {

    /**
     * I've also tried this without the init hook with the same results
     */

    add_action('init', function() {
      add_action( 'gform_after_submission', array($this, 'collectGFData'), 10, 2 );
    });
    

  } // end construct


  public function collectGFData($entry, $form ) {
    error_log("form was submitted");

    ob_start();
    var_dump($entry);
    $entryTesting = ob_end_clean();
    error_log("entry was $entryTesting");

    ob_start();
    var_dump($form);
    $formTesting = ob_end_clean();
    error_log("form was $formTesting");

    $formID = rgar( $entry, 'form_id' );
    $dateCreated = rgar( $entry, 'date_created' );


    ob_start();
    var_dump($dateCreated);
    $dateCreatedTesting = ob_end_clean();
    error_log("date created testing was $dateCreatedTesting");

    ob_start();
    var_dump($formID);
    $formIDTesting = ob_end_clean();
    error_log("form id testing was $formIDTesting");


 

  } // end collectGFData

}

$gformService = new GravityFormService();
```

In my error log after submitting the form, I get the following in my log file:

```
[27-Feb-2021 20:17:02 UTC] form was submitted
[27-Feb-2021 20:17:02 UTC] entry was 1
[27-Feb-2021 20:17:02 UTC] form was 1
[27-Feb-2021 20:17:02 UTC] date created testing was 1
[27-Feb-2021 20:17:02 UTC] form id testing was 1
[27-Feb-2021 20:17:02 UTC] confirmation number testing was 1
```

Gravity forms version = 2.4.22

WordPress version = 5.6.2

PHP v. 7.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Gravity Forms, it's [`ob_end_clean()`](https://www.php.net/ob_end_clean), which just deletes the buffer and returns a boolean value. (In this case, `true`, which is getting expressed as `1`.)

Is there a pressing reason to use the `ob_*` functions? The code would be more readable (and predictable) if it was something like this.

```
public function collectGFData($entry, $form ) {
    error_log("form was submitted");
    error_log("entry was " . print_r( $entry. 1) );
    error_log("form was " . print_r( $form, 1 ) );

    $formID = rgar( $entry, 'form_id' );
    $dateCreated = rgar( $entry, 'date_created' );
    error_log("date created testing was " . print_r( $dateCreated, 1 ) );
    error_log("form id testing was " . print_r( $formID, 1 ) );
}
```

...using [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/print_r) instead of [`var_dump()`](https://www.php.net/var_dump).

Comment: I switched editors, and my auto complete was using ob_end_clean(). I meant to use ob_get_clean(). ob_get_clean() has it working perfectly.